# What does $ \mathbb{E}^n $ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

There is an article, where instead of the usual $ \mathbb{R}^n $ I've found $ \mathbb{E}^n $. There is no explanation why. It just uses it.

As far as I remember $ \mathbb{E} $ is the same as $ \mathbb{R} $, but it includes positive and negative infinity. But I'm not sure

What does it really mean?

Comment: Could you maybe provide a reference to that article?

Comment: Extended reals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line ?

Comment: Ys but th wikipdia articl nvr uss th notation $\Bbb{E}$.

Comment: Some authors use $E^n$ for Euclidean $n$-space. Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: The article is about curve fitting. It is not in english, but I will translate the relevant part, and copy it here

Comment: Thanks for offering to translate parts of the paper, but you don't have to: MSE is not an exclusively English forum.

Comment: You'll see $E^n$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a lot of older books and articles; it seems pretty old fashioned from what I can tell. There may be contexts I'm unfamiliar with that still use it. I have never seen it to refer to $n$-dimensional extended reals, though I suppose such a usage is possible; it just doesn't strike me as a very useful space to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm E^n$, or sometimes $\Bbb E^n$, refers to $n$-dimensional euclidean space. Unlike $\Bbb R^n$, it does not carry with it a particular origin or preferred set of axes.

Comment: @RobArthan No need to be a jerk about it.

Comment: @RobArthan: Please point out a single aspect of the answer that is factually incorrect or irrelevant to the question. I regret that I am not able to downvote your comments.

Comment: @Rahul Thankfully, I can upvote yours. :)

Comment: @RobArthan That does sound like a likely outcome. Reading math papers is dangerous business.

Comment: @RobArthan: The notation $E^n$ (sic) in your comment might refer to various things in different contexts. The roman letter $\mathrm E$ in $\mathrm E^n$ indicates a unique canonical meaning. What other meanings do you have in mind for it?

Comment: @RobArthan: The OP states that he was expecting to see $\Bbb R^n$. Indeed, many authors use $\Bbb R^n$ when its additional structure is harmless—albeit irrelevant—when actually $\mathrm E^n$ would be appropriate, perhaps because the more concrete $\Bbb R^n$ is familiar. My answer is based on long experience of such notation, combined with the above considerations. I am unhappy that you accuse me of making up answers based on guesswork and generally not caring about intellectual rigour.  I would withdraw my answer if, contrary to my present belief, it were shown to be wrong.

Comment: @JohnBentin: all you need to do to make me happy with your answer is just to qualify it with "I think" or "In my experience" or "what I think your problem is". The OP has given no information about the article he or she is reading, so any answer is a guess.